# How to store date value to a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, date, date-format

i tried the below codes and got result like this [3],[4]

j = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, dtpFrom.Value, dtpTo.Value)

```
    Dim str2 As String = String.Empty
    Dim str3 As String = String.Empty

    Dim dat2 As Date = dtpFrom.Value
    For i As Integer = 1 To j + 1
        If str2.Trim().Length > 0 Then
            str2 = str2 & ","
        End If
        str2 = str2 & "[" & dat2.ToString("MM") & "]"

        dat2 = dat2.AddMonths(1)
    Next
```

I need a str like this -> [3] Mar,[4] Apr
Is it possible?

Comment: How to use MonthName function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the month name you have to use `dat2.ToString("MMM")`

You can find [here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_date_tostring_custom.html) more date options

Comment: This answer is useful (but doesn't really answers the question)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options but the easiest to read for this date is `String.Format`.

Something like this should do it:

```
   Dim d As Date = DateTime.Now
   Dim s As String = String.Format("[{0:MM}] {0:MMM}", d)

   Debug.WriteLine(s) 'Outputs [10] Oct
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information